# JMeter OS Process Sampler/error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: macos, jmeter

I am completely new to the JMeter, so question might be silly and pretty simple. I am trying to test my C++ executable compress in JMeter by using OS Process Sampler, but get an error. I also test everything in cmd and it works in there. I feel like problem is related with command field and maybe I need to also add command parameters. The path to the executable is: "/Users/armanenginsucu/Projects/CERN:GSoC/compress"

Following is the picture of the paths that I passed to the sampler:
[image]
This is the error I get:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the error it clearly states that - it cannot find the file (./compress doc.docx)

1. It is better to provide the full path for the file (/Users/armanenginsucu/Projects/compress\ doc.docx)
2. You need to provide escaping sequence for the spaces (compress\ doc.docx) - alternatively you can rename the file without spaces

Hopefully that will resolve your issue

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I provide the full path: /Users/armanenginsucu/Projects/CERN:GSoC/compress. and ./compress doc.docx is the command to execute the executable. I have read that command sectin of jmeter should be in this format: "/path/to/your/executable command arguments". But clearly smt is wrong. I also tried to provide escaping sequences but problem remains unfortunately

Comment: You can try providing the input file path in command parameters field

Answer (score 0):

Command-line arguments is a feature of [Unix shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell)

My expectation is that you need to amend your [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) configuration to look like:

[image]

---

Alternatively you can use [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and the following [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) code

```
"/bin/zsh /Users/armanenginsucu/Projects/CERN:GSoC/compress /Users/armanenginsucu/Projects/CERN:GSoC/compress/doc.docx".execute().text
```